# Separating entity framework into a separate project and using POCOs in presentation layer

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have just started using EF6.0 and am putting it into its own layer.  How do I expose the POCOs to the service layer that my UI interfaces with?  I'm using a generic Repo pattern as well.  So far I have

1. Data Layer - EF6.0
2. Repo layer - Generic Repo - references Data Layer
3. Service layer - business logic - References Repo Layer
4. UI layer - References Service Layer

I'm currently playing with some code in the service layer and I've suddenly realized that the service layer does not recognize the POCO names. I could add a reference to the Data layer but this defeats the object in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate/move the poco classes to their own project